# Regex to isolate two digits in middle of string

Tags: regex

I have couple of strings

`Staten Island\31R722`

`Manhattan\03M185`

`Queens\24Q058`

where I would like to isolate and output two digits after `\`

Output for

`Staten Island\31R722` should be `31`
`Manhattan\03M185` should be `03`
`Queens\24Q058` should be `24`

This is the regex I have so far

`\w+\s*\w+\\`

I'm not sure how to eliminate the single letter and three characters after it.

It is always a single letter and three characters.

Comment: Try `(?<=\\)\d+` or if you're using JavaScript: `\\(\d+` or using your solution: `\w+\s*\w+\\(\d+)`

Comment: which lang you're running?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm trying to incorporate this into MS SQL replace statement. Website I'm using is `http://regexr.com/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^\w+(?:\s+\w+)?\\|[A-Z].*$
```

You can use this and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rX1tE6/5

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
.*\\([0-9]+).*
```

Replacement string:

```
\1
```

or `$1`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vO0zJ0/1)